# How to read CGMiner output?

Tags: c#, cmd, bitcoin

I am trying to read the CGMiner output in a C# program I am writing.  I successfully read/write the standard thread input/output.  But for some reason CGMiner does not write to the standard cmd window output, and I can't read it in C#.  Any ideas?

This is my process start:

```
    public void start() {
        proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => updateConsoleOutput(e);
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine(); 
    }
```

This is the function I use to write to the console:

```
    public void RunCommand(string cmd = "") {
        if (cmd.Length > 0) {
            ConsoleInput = cmd;
        }
        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(ConsoleInput);
        myStreamWriter.Flush();
        ConsoleInput = String.Empty;
    }
```

These are the functions I use to read from the console:

```
    public delegate void consoleOutputCallback(string message);
    private void updateConsoleOutput(DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new consoleOutputCallback(updateConsoleText),
                new object[] { outLine.Data }
            );
        }
    }
    public void updateConsoleText(string message) {
        this.OutputBlock.Text += message + "\n";
    }
```

HINT:  Don't know if it helps, but CGMiner will overwrite the entire console window, and cursor always stay at top left and does not move.  All command before running CGMiner is overwritten.

---

Forgot to add, this is console command I use:

```
cd C:\cgminer\
del *.bin
cgminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3335 -O yongke.1:x -g 2
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the **--per-device-stats** flag in order for GPU stats to be written into stream

And **don't forget to add** this to the code in question

```
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => updateConsoleOutput(e);
....
proc.Start();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Most of miners use standart Error stream instead of standart Output stream (to write both output data and errors) for some reason..

Comment: @Michael Rudner Evanchik I've updated my answer - check it now

Comment: @Michael Rudner Evanchik I've forget `proc.BeginErrorReadLine()` - I've updated my answer once again

Answer (score -1):

the only thing that made it work for me was

```
-T
```

here is my working code

```
Task StartGPUMiner(object set)
    {
        MinerParams m = new MinerParams();
        m = (MinerParams)set;
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = m.ApplicationPath + "\\cgminer\\cgminer.exe";
        start.Arguments = " -I " + m.GpuIntisity + " -T --scrypt -o " + m.sProtocol + m.ServerName + ":" +  m.ServerPort + " -u " + m.UserName + "." + m.WorkerName + " -p " + m.ThePassword + " " + m.GpuParams;
        start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;

        var proc = Process.Start(start);
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    txtLog.Text += (e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
                });
            }
            catch { }
        };

        try
        {
            proc.Exited += (s, e) => tcs.SetResult(null);
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
        catch { }
            return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate the answer.

Comment: I've tried **-T** or **--text-only** flag instead of **--per-device-stats**. For me it's working only for benchmark mode. If connecting via **stratum+tcp** - the last data I receive is `probing for alive pool`. **Win 7 Ult 64bit SP1 + .NET 4.0 + cgminer 3.7.2**